# Javascript event handler function is missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
  <select name="catid" id="post_catid" onchange="getSubCat(this.value, 'post_subcatid')" style="width:150px;" class="right ">
```

What happens if the getSubCat function that handles the onchange event is not defined or missing in code?

Comment: Trying it would of taken less time than it took to write this post. (My 2 cents).

Comment: @stef Don't assume that OP knows about the error console in the browser...

Comment: i didn't see any errors yet the functionality was working... don't have much javascript experience... so wanted to know how browser/javascript handled events for which it couldn't find the event handler definition... didn't know about console until  i installed firebug on someone's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get a JavaScript error on every change event for that select (which many users won't notice).  If you had any code inline after the getSubCat it would not be reached.  That's about it.

Comment: i suppose this answer is correct since someone who helped me fix the issue also asked me if i could see any error messages from javascript. +1 for all others. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing, it just won't run it as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

An error is thrown whenever the change event is fired at that SELECT element:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getSubCat is
>   not defined

Answer (score 1):

The page will load without error, but if the event occurs (i.e. someone changes the dropdown), you'll get

`Uncaught ReferenceError: getSubCat is not defined`